# Empty destructor vs literal destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, constexpr, user-defined-literals

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
        constexpr Test(const int x) : _x(x) {}
        constexpr int get() const {return _x;}
        ~Test() {} // HERE
    protected:
        const int _x;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr Test test(5);
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the line `HERE` the code compiles well, but if I define an empty destructor, it results to a compilation error saying that `Test` is non-literal.

Why and what is the difference between an empty destructor and no destructor at all ?

EDIT: Another related question : if empty and literal destructors are different how to define a protected literal destructor ?

Comment: You can't have a non-trivial destructor in a constexpr object.

Comment: Protected destructor = almost never a good idea.

Comment: I need them for some abstract CRTP classes.

Comment: Difference: **12.4 Destructors [class.dtor]**

*3) [...] A destructor is trivial if it is implicitly-declared and if: [...]*

Comment: You can do `~Test() = default;`, I think.

Comment: @Vincent In that case why not make the *constructor* `protected` instead of the destructor?

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I have asked the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14256208/882932

Comment: @KonradRudolph If some class is intended to be a base class for other ones, its destructor should be either virtual or protected to prevent UB when derived object is deleted via base pointer.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Just that you don't have to mess with virtual destructors when you're not going to polymorphically destroy objects at all.

Comment: @Tadeusz If the class isn’t polymorphic then how in hell did you get a pointer/reference to it via its base? That is a bug, you mustn’t use CRTP like that.

Comment: @Tadeusz I think there is no point in protecting against something that won't happen accidentally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quotes from n3376

7.1.5/9

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have
> literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant
> expression

3.9/10

> A type is a literal type if:
>
> it has a trivial destructor...

12.4/5

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> — the destructor is not virtual,
>
> — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
>
> — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
> class has a trivial destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is non-trivial.

clang diagnostic is really more informative:

```
error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const C'

'C' is not literal because it has a user-provided destructor
```

Comment: Clang: 1254, Everyone Else: 32

Comment: @chris: Sorry for my unknowledge, but what does your comment mean?

Comment: @axeoth, It was a play on how good Clang is with its errors being readable and/or helpful compared to other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

No destructor causes the compiler to add a trivial destructor, which is ill defined in the spec, but basically does nothing.

If you specify a destructor, it does not add the trivial destructor.  Your destructor is non-trivial.

In your case, `Test::~Test() { }` looks pretty darn trivial, but that is a human interpretation of what you see.  To go further, what about:

```
Test::~Test()
{
    int a = 5;
}
```

We can see that an optimizer can optimize out a, so it is obviously doing nothing.  How about:

```
Test::~Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 2) {
        if ((i % 2) == 1)
            doSomeSideEffect(); // like throwing or setting a global
    }
}
```

We can see that `i` can never be odd, so that destructor does nothing.

The spec has to define what is allowed to be a constexpr and what cannot.  Rather than going down this rabbit hole of defining "doing nothing," they simply declare that the only do-nothing destructor that is good enough for constexpr is the compiler provided trivial destructor.